# What to do with my questions which have not been solved?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

What should I do with unanswered questions of mine, or questions with answers that don't help, if I don't have an answer either? In many cases, I would prefer not to give out a bounty, especially if I don't need an answer anymore.

Comment: Are you talking about *your* unanswered questions, or just all unanswered questions in general?

Comment: If they're your own questions and you've solved the problem in some way you can state how in an answer yourself and accept that answer.

Comment: @JasonPlank, I am talking about my own questions.

Comment: This is a valid question that I too have wondered; why so many downers?

Comment: I've tried to find an answer in the FAQ, but found nothing...

Comment: @chown [Because downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException - I understand that, but this isnt a feature request or even an opinion to disagree with, its a request for advice.

Comment: Could be people don't think you should do anything at all. Could be people think the question is useless. Could be people think this has been asked before. Could be people having a bad day. Could be a lack of freehand circles in the post. Could be anything, the point is that the answer to "why the downvote" when on meta is: "Just Because" :-)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException - Point taken :)

Comment: @chown I had downvoted because the original meaning was ambiguous. Withdrew downvote as it has been clarified.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're talking about your own questions:

- See  if your question  is unclear in any way and correct/improve it. Perhaps the clarification will spark new interest.
- Add that the answers you received so far unfortunately don't answer your question. Clearly state why they don't, because obviously the people who answered think they do. (This is actually my first suggestion in disguise)
- If you don't want to add a bounty (and if the first two points didn't change the situation), accept that you'll just have to wait and see.
- If you don't really need an answer, then why ask? ;) Although a question of use to the wide SO community is of course more than welcome.
- If you **no longer** need the answer, either add your solution (if you've found one) as an answer, or treat the question as you would have (perhaps taking the first two points into account) should you still have needed the answer. Questions on SO are not just for your own benefit, but also for the community as a whole. Even if it no longer applies to you, it might help others.

Comment: Re last point - you can decide not to implement something if you don't know how to implement that.

Comment: To expand on @LA_'s comment.  If you have already asked and needed to know at some point in the past, but now the issue is no longer a problem that needs to be fixed, but you never did find an answer (and dont care about even getting an answer anymore), what then?